# How to properly use cleos get table with --key-type sha256 / secondary index (failing on 1.4.2)

Tags: table, api

I am not able to filter a hash correctly, using get table / get_table_rows. Also I noticed that the abi is not generating a secondary index, although I am assuming this is not the problem, since anyway it is returning something.

Any tip would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
cleos get table testtesttest testtesttest hasher --index 2 --key-type sha256 -L 45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4de
```

is returning 3 rows instead of 1

```
{
  "rows": [{
      "id": 0,
      "owner": "test1",
      "hash": "cb285a3e234c39b13b170a4cc376bd002640f270d8219fe2c2f93d8c9c53491a",
      "tx": "e5aa66ed5b24a2c236257d79225de7d05bb85ad41181d3f4bd4a5c35e65d64f0"
    },{
      "id": 1,
      "owner": "test1",
      "hash": "45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4de",
      "tx": "388cbcb1351e17a7441be6513ab7d54d62eadcc32cdbafed22de43cf7584da60"
    },{
      "id": 2,
      "owner": "test1",
      "hash": "39b9193df3f4caf1518696ff85942b1dd40f3bbfb989d8f6703228dda8d28e54",
      "tx": "a021da6dec167cd4f1b6d4440061ab9273e159791c0d6ca106b3c7d72178c62b"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

Table implementation works within smartcontract (I am using the hash to check existance), but it is not working from cleos get table.

```
  private:
    TABLE hasher_rec
    {
        uint64_t id;
        name owner;
        capi_checksum256 hash;
        capi_checksum256 tx;

        uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
        fixed_bytes<32> by_hash() const { return checksum256_to_sha256(hash); } // key256 replaced with digest256 = typedef fixed_bytes<32>

        static fixed_bytes<32> checksum256_to_sha256(const capi_checksum256 &hash)
        {
            const uint64_t *p64 = reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t *>(&hash);
            return fixed_bytes<32>::make_from_word_sequence<uint64_t>(p64[0], p64[1], p64[2], p64[3]);
        }        


        EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(hasher_rec, (id)(owner)(hash)(tx))
    };
    typedef multi_index<name("hasher"), hasher_rec, 
        indexed_by<name("hash"), const_mem_fun<hasher_rec, fixed_bytes<32>, &hasher_rec::by_hash>>
        > hasher_table_type;

    hasher_table_type _hasher;
```

This is the abi

```
"tables": [
    {
        "name": "hasher",
        "type": "hasher_rec",
        "index_type": "i64",
        "key_names": [],
        "key_types": []
    }
],
```

I tried changing it to

```
"tables": [
    {
        "name": "hasher",
        "type": "hasher_rec",
        "index_type": "i64",
        "key_names": ["hash"],
        "key_types": ["sha256"]
    }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: To anyone interested: confirmed bug here -- https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/6648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@gustavomick , I think the issue is with the way you pack key256 in `checksum256_to_sha256`

I tested your code with

```
static key256 checksum256_to_sha256(const checksum256 &hash)
{
const uint128_t *p128 = reinterpret_cast<const uint128_t *>(&hash);            
key256 k;
k.data()[0] = p128[0];
k.data()[1] = p128[1];
return k;
}
```

And it worked like a charm .

Here is your code refactored

```
include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class test256 : public contract {
    struct hasher_rec;

public:
    test256(account_name self) : contract{self}, _hasher{_self,_self} {}

    //@abi action
    void addhash(const hasher_rec &rec) {
       _hasher.emplace(_self, [&](auto &&r) { //payer = _self
           r = rec;
       });
    }
private:
    ///@abi table hasher i64
    struct hasher_rec
    {
        uint64_t id;
        name owner;
        checksum256 hash;
        checksum256 tx;

        uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
        key256 by_hash() const { return checksum256_to_sha256(hash); } // key256 replaced with digest256 = typedef fixed_bytes<32>

        static key256 checksum256_to_sha256(const checksum256 &hash)
        {
            const uint128_t *p128 = reinterpret_cast<const uint128_t *>(&hash);
            //return key256::make_from_word_sequence<uint64_t>(p64[0], p64[1], p64[2], p64[3]);
            key256 k;
            k.data()[0] = p128[0];
            k.data()[1] = p128[1];
            return k;
        }

        EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(hasher_rec, (id)(owner)(hash)(tx))
    };
typedef multi_index<N(hasher), hasher_rec,
        indexed_by<N(hash), const_mem_fun<hasher_rec, key256, &hasher_rec::by_hash>>
        > hasher_table_type;

    hasher_table_type _hasher;

};

EOSIO_ABI( test256, (addhash))
```

Commands to insert records:

```
cleos push action testchecksum addhash '{"rec":{"id":"0" ,"owner":"testchecksum","hash":"cb285a3e234c39b13b170a4cc376bd002640f270d8219fe2c2f93d8c9c53491a","tx":"e5aa66ed5b24a2c236257d79225de7d05bb85ad41181d3f4bd4a5c35e65d64f0"}}' -p testchecksum


cleos push action testchecksum addhash '{"rec":{"id":"1" ,"owner":"testchecksum","hash":"45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4de","tx":"388cbcb1351e17a7441be6513ab7d54d62eadcc32cdbafed22de43cf7584da60"}}' -p testchecksum


cleos push action testchecksum addhash '{"rec":{"id":"2" ,"owner":"testchecksum","hash":"39b9193df3f4caf1518696ff85942b1dd40f3bbfb989d8f6703228dda8d28e5","tx":"a021da6dec167cd4f1b6d4440061ab9273e159791c0d6ca106b3c7d72178c62b"}}' -p testchecksum
```

Command to read from table:

```
cleos get table testchecksum testchecksum  hasher --index 2 --key-type sha256 -L45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4de  -U45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4df



{
  "rows": [{
      "id": 1,
      "owner": "testchecksum",
      "hash": "45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4de",
      "tx": "388cbcb1351e17a7441be6513ab7d54d62eadcc32cdbafed22de43cf7584da60"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

You also need to remove old data from the table. I just removed $EOSROOT/eosio/nodeos/data

Comment: @gustavomick no worries, I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
cleos get table testtesttest testtesttest hasher --index 2 --key-type sha256 -L 45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4de
```

This command giving you 3 rows because of usage of scope. Here i am assuming deployment account is testtesttest so scope declaration may be like this `table_name taba(_self,_self.value)`. that's why it gives you three rows. 
if you change scope from only owne to between user and owner(assuming deployment account is testtesttest and user account is testuser) 
`table_name taba(_self,_user)` then you need to use to get ony one row per user.

```
cleos get table testtesttest testuser taba
```

Comment: thanks, should not I expect 0 rows if it's out of scope?

Comment: In addition , your id2 < id1 , so you will get 2 rows , -L is lower bound means less or equals , you need to pair it with -U flag upper bound e.g strickt greater then, so simply add `-U 45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4df` increment the last `e` to the next `f` that will give you exact match on your id

Comment: thanks i think is a good call but seems not be working for me. something else seems to be happening.

Comment: yes if it is not in scope then it will give 0 rows

Comment: @Mr.Y so there is a bug or ..?

Comment: No there is not a bug actually it is the way that how eosio works

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/multi_index.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class[[eosio::contract]] test256  : public contract
{
  struct hasher_rec;

  public:
    using contract::contract;

    test256(name self, name code, datastream<const char *> ds)  : contract(self, code, ds), _hasher(_self,_self.value) {}

    [[eosio::action]] 
     void addhash(const hasher_rec &rec) {
       _hasher.emplace(_self, [&](auto &&r) { 
           r = rec;
       });
    }

 private: 

    struct [[eosio::table]] hasher_rec {
        uint64_t id;
        name owner;
        checksum256 hash;
        checksum256 tx;

        uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }

        key256 by_hash() const { return checksum256_to_sha256(hash); }

        static key256 checksum256_to_sha256(const checksum256 &hash)
        {
            const uint128_t *p128 = reinterpret_cast<const uint128_t *>(&hash);
            //return key256::make_from_word_sequence<uint64_t>(p64[0], p64[1], p64[2], p64[3]);
            key256 k;
            k.data()[0] = p128[0];
            k.data()[1] = p128[1];
            return k;
        }

        // EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(hasher_rec, (id)(owner)(hash)(tx))
    };

    typedef multi_index<"hasher"_n, hasher_rec,
        indexed_by<"hash"_n, const_mem_fun<hasher_rec, key256, &hasher_rec::by_hash>>
        > hasher_table_type;

    hasher_table_type _hasher;
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(test256, (addhash))
```

**From command line:**

```
cleos push action testchecksum addhash '{"rec":{"id":"0" ,"owner":"testchecksum","hash":"cb285a3e234c39b13b170a4cc376bd002640f270d8219fe2c2f93d8c9c53491a","tx":"e5aa66ed5b24a2c236257d79225de7d05bb85ad41181d3f4bd4a5c35e65d64f0"}}'
-p testchecksum


cleos push action testchecksum addhash '{"rec":{"id":"1" ,"owner":"testchecksum","hash":"45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4de","tx":"388cbcb1351e17a7441be6513ab7d54d62eadcc32cdbafed22de43cf7584da60"}}'
-p testchecksum
```

**Can retrieve all rows (no upper/lower):**

```
dom@SCP-EOS3:~/scp-eos/contracts/eos$ cleos get table scoopowner scoopowner hasher --index 2 --key-type i256 {   "rows": [{
      "id": 1,
      "owner": "testchecksum",
      "hash": "45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4de",
      "tx": "e5aa66ed5b24a2c236257d79225de7d05bb85ad41181d3f4bd4a5c35e65d64f0"
    },{
      "id": 0,
      "owner": "testchecksum",
      "hash": "cb285a3e234c39b13b170a4cc376bd002640f270d8219fe2c2f93d8c9c53491a",
      "tx": "e5aa66ed5b24a2c236257d79225de7d05bb85ad41181d3f4bd4a5c35e65d64f0"
    }   ],   "more": false }
```

**Cannot retrieve by upper/lower specification:**

```
dom@SCP-EOS3:~/scp-eos/contracts/eos$ cleos get table scoopowner scoopowner hasher --index 2 --key-type sha256 -L 45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23402b735de61ce2912c86bac4dd -U 45d944598dccadd8c5a56e29c9786f05fa4b23 402b735de61ce2912c86bac4df {   "rows": [],   "more": false }
```