# How to use checksum256 secondary index to get table rows

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

Does anyone know the correct way to get table rows using `checksum256` (`fixed_bytes<32>`) secondary index through the `get_table_rows` RPC API?

I found [a way using `key256`](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/how-to-properly-use-cleos-get-table-with-key-type-sha256-secondary-index-fa?rq=1), but `key256` is deprecated in eosio.cdt 1.5.0.

```
warning: 'key256' is deprecated: Replaced by fixed_bytes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

So I implemented a contract with `checksum256` secondary index referring to [this document](https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.5.0/group__multiindex.html), but I can't get proper rows using `checksum256` secondary index. [My contract](https://kylin.eosx.io/account/checksumtest) is as follows, and I compile it with eosio.cdt 1.5.0.

```cpp
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract]] test : public contract
{
  using contract::contract;

public:

  test(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds) :
      contract(receiver, code, ds),
      items(_self, _self.value)
  {};

  [[eosio::action]]
  void additem(std::string identifier)
  {
    items.emplace(_self, [&](auto& row) {
                           row.key             = items.available_primary_key();
                           row.identifier      = identifier;
                           row.identifier_hash = hash(identifier);
                         });
  }

private:

  struct [[eosio::table]] item {
    uint64_t key;
    std::string identifier;
    checksum256 identifier_hash;
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return key; }
    checksum256 by_identifier_hash() const { return identifier_hash; }
  };
  typedef multi_index<name("items"), item,
                      indexed_by<name("idhash"), const_mem_fun<item, checksum256, &item::by_identifier_hash>>
                      > item_index;

  checksum256 hash(std::string str)
  {
    return sha256(const_cast<char*>(str.c_str()), str.size());
  }

  item_index items;
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(test, (additem));
```

```sh
$ cleos -u https://api-kylin.eosasia.one push action checksumtest additem '["m0t0k1ch1"]' -p checksumtest@active
```

```sh
$ curl -s https://api-kylin.eosasia.one/v1/chain/get_table_rows -d '{"json":true,"code":"checksumtest","scope":"checksumtest","table":"items","table_key":"idhash","index_position":2,"key_type":"sha256","limit":1}'
```

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": 0,
      "identifier": "m0t0k1ch1",
      "identifier_hash": "c5bae5b3f19a69d45594902726ce983c0948fcda5bbf408f893fff91298688b4"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

```sh
$ curl -s https://api-kylin.eosasia.one/v1/chain/get_table_rows -d '{"json":true,"code":"checksumtest","scope":"checksumtest","table":"items","table_key":"idhash","index_position":2,"key_type":"sha256","lower_bound":"c5bae5b3f19a69d45594902726ce983c0948fcda5bbf408f893fff91298688b4","upper_bound":"c5bae5b3f19a69d45594902726ce983c0948fcda5bbf408f893fff91298688b4","limit":1}'
```

```
{
  "rows": [],
  "more": false
}
```

---

### Updated on Mar 18, 2019

It seems that the `checksum256` data is divided into two parts per 16 bytes, and each part is stored in little endian. So I was able to get the proper row in the following way.

```sh
$ curl -s https://api-kylin.eosasia.one/v1/chain/get_table_rows -d '{"json":true,"code":"checksumtest","scope":"checksumtest","table":"items","table_key":"idhash","index_position":2,"key_type":"sha256","lower_bound":"3c98ce2627909455d4699af1b3e5bac5b488862991ff3f898f40bf5bdafc4809","upper_bound":"3c98ce2627909455d4699af1b3e5bac5b488862991ff3f898f40bf5bdafc4809","limit":1}'
```

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": 0,
      "identifier": "m0t0k1ch1",
      "identifier_hash": "c5bae5b3f19a69d45594902726ce983c0948fcda5bbf408f893fff91298688b4"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

Thank you for [the advice](https://twitter.com/CoRe1o3/status/1107277661024354304), [@CoRe1o3](https://twitter.com/CoRe1o3)

See also [this issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/6522).

Comment: Could you explain how you converted the returned checksum256 into the value you sent to the API? Clicking translate on each tweet is quite cumbersome and it would be useful to have the full explanation in this answer :)

Answer (score 9):

Some further explanation of how the value to pass via cleos was derived. As already mentioned in the original post, this all revolves around [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). For some reason the `checksum256` value is returned in a different endian to what the index key type bounds for `sha256` expects.

If you have the below hash (`checksum256`) returned by a row in the table:

`7af12386a82b6337d6b1e4c6a1119e29bb03e6209aa03c70ed3efbb9b74a290c`

It's first split into two parts (16 bytes each side):

`7af12386a82b6337d6b1e4c6a1119e29` `bb03e6209aa03c70ed3efbb9b74a290c`

Each part is then reversed in 2 character (1 byte) chunks, using the first part as an example:

`7af12386a82b6337d6b1e4c6a1119e29`

`7a` `f1` `23` `86` `a8` `2b` `63` `37` `d6` `b1` `e4` `c6` `a1` `11` `9e` `29`

`29` `9e` `11` `a1` `c6` `e4` `b1` `d6` `37` `63` `2b` `a8` `86` `23` `f1` `7a`

The two reversed parts are then concatenated to form the value you can use with the `sha256` index key type:

`299e11a1c6e4b1d637632ba88623f17a` `0c294ab7b9fb3eed703ca09a20e603bb`

The final result:

`299e11a1c6e4b1d637632ba88623f17a0c294ab7b9fb3eed703ca09a20e603bb`

Comment: There's an ongoing discussion on github https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/6648

Comment: Yup, I made a comment on that issue and linked to this issue :)

Answer (score 2):

## 2020 Update for eosio 2.0 & eosio.cdt 1.7

I know this post is old but for anyone else who stumbles upon this. The encoding as described by Jason Bert's answer (https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/4344/3464) is no longer required, as far as I can tell from my tests.

**Simply use the the hash directly within `lower_bound` and/or `upper_bound` as expected**